# How change the size of an uploaded image in codeigniter without creating a thump image?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

We can generate different thumps of an uploaded image.
That makes several copies of that image.
I want only one image to be uploaded.
But in view,it have to make available in different sizes.
Anyone Know how to do it?

Comment: To create thumbs of images has the advantage that no **big** images have to be transferred for the user to select which image he/she wants to see in detail. You could - on the fly, when an image is requested - transform it ad hoc and send this image out. However with this approach you would loose time for the transformation each time an image is requested.

Comment: Show the code of what have you tried so far. Before that, you can also read [this article](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) of how to ask question.

Comment: hello hherger ,r u telling creating thumps are the best way?. the size of the image folder wil increased.

Comment: What @hherger is trying to say is that you can decide whether to save thumbs or only have one image saved and transform it to the required size when you show it. Both options have their pros and cons.

Comment: Cool Acid@ in your opinion which is the best way?

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP library called `phpThumb()`. `phpThumb()` uses the GD library to create thumbnails from images on the fly.

you can dynamically create image thumbnails

```
<?php

function image_thumb( $image_path, $height, $width )
 {
    $CI =& get_instance();

    // Path to image thumbnail
    $image_thumb = dirname( $image_path ) . '/' . $height . '_' . $width . '.jpg';

    if ( !file_exists( $image_thumb ) ) {
        // LOAD LIBRARY
        $CI->load->library( 'image_lib' );

        // CONFIGURE IMAGE LIBRARY
        $config['image_library']    = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image']     = $image_path;
        $config['new_image']        = $image_thumb;
        $config['maintain_ratio']   = TRUE;
        $config['height']           = $height;
        $config['width']            = $width;
        $CI->image_lib->initialize( $config );
        $CI->image_lib->resize();
        $CI->image_lib->clear();
    }

    return '<img src="' . dirname( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] ) . '/' . $image_thumb . '" />';
}
```

usage in View:

```
echo image_thumb( 'assets/images/picture-1/picture-1.jpg', 50, 50 );
```